# Can't launch windows 8, trying to use Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Alright, so I have no idea if I'm even posting this properly so here goes nothing.

I guess I cold halted and it messed up my hard drive, leaving me stuck on a repair screen that never works.  I tried booting with the Windows 8 disk I had to reinstall, but I need a product code I no longer have.

I found (using Hiren's bootCD) that all my files had been moved to a found.000 folder, which seems to be the problem. I'm unsure if my hard drive is actually broken though. I used the chksys command (can't remember the actual name for the life of me), but it didn't work, so I'm feeling the hard drive might be broken.

I'm left with either buying an ssd to replace the hard drive, or another Windows 8, unsure if either would work. I decided that instead of buying a new Windows, I would just make a bootable ubuntu disc and install Ubuntu instead of reinstalling Windows.

The problem is, unlike when I boot up through the windows disc to reinstall, booting through the linux disc doesn't work. It seems to be ignored and I get sent to the perpetually failing Windows auto repair.

Why can't I boot through the ubuntu disc? I downloaded the iso and burned it to a CD-R. Is it because my hard drive is broken?

As you can see, I'm pretty noob, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

tl; dr: Can't boot through ubuntu installation disc, need help.

Answer (score 0):

First check if in your boot sequence the CD/DVD is before HDD.
(you can do this either by entering in BIOS, usually by pressing DEL or F2 in the beginning or by entering in quick boot menu (usually F10 or F12))

If yes, and you can't still boot from CD/DVD, you should use an ubuntu distribution that supports UEFI boot (14.04 supports it)...

Comment: I changed my boot sequence to boot from disks, which I checked was working by having the pc boot into Hiren's and Kasterky's rescue CD with no problem. But the ubuntu disc is still being ignored, not sure why. I have the latest version from the website, which I believe is 14.04.01.